# Chromium forgets passwords stored in kwallet after upgrade

Tags: chrome, kwallet, plasma5

Already asked this question on the Arch forum, got no useful answer, so I try it here as well, perhaps someone sometime experienced something similar, maybe on some other Linux flavor.

After a recent Arch upgrade chromium forgot all my passwords. I use plasma5, and my chromium passwords are stored in a kwallet.

*Kwallet-manager tells me that my passwords are still stored there and the wallet is open and chromium gets connected to it.*

Yet, chromium tells me that it has no stored passwords.
The upgrade touched both kwallet and chromium:
kwallet (5.16.0-2 -> 5.17.0-1)
chromium (47.0.2526.80-2 -> 47.0.2526.106-2)

Starting chromium from konsole with

```
    chromium --password-store=kwallet`
```

has the effect of chromium rediscovering the passwords (I have to use the switch every time I start chromium, for without the switch, the passwords are gone). This leaves two questions unanswered:

1. Looking into kwallet was the default behavior previously under plasma 5, but not anymore? (Note: both variables `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP` are set to the value `KDE`)
2. Without the switch, why does kwallet-manager indicate that chromium is connected even though it doesn’t look for the passwords there?

Comment: After a chromium update on Ubuntu (from 47.0.2526 to 48.0.2564), the kwallet popup doesn't accept my master password anymore.  I'm quite sure I didn't just forget my password.  IDK if it's related to this post or not.  Hmm, I should prob. just try downgrading the package.